# Can I somehow alias R in Android?

Tags: java, android, git, android-resources

I have two Android applications that share 90% of their code with each other, and due to political reasons (I think also technical reasons) need to have separate package names (so they'll appear under different URLs in Google Play)

I use git with two branches for each app, and I sync the two branches manually before each release. When running a diff command of the two branches, a lot of my files are different when in reality the only thing that's different is the package name of the auto generated file R, so for the first application I have 15 files with

```
import pkg.name.one.R;
```

and for the other app

```
import pkg.name.two.R;
```

I want to somehow import `R` in the same way for both classes.

I tried wrapping R like so:

package thescene;

```
public class RWrapper {

    public class R extends pkg.name.one.R {}

}
```

(which would make `RWrapper` the only different file between these two branches in regards to the source or `R`) but alas `R` is a final class (and I'm not even sure this would've worked anyway)

So it there a way to somehow alias the R class in a way that would allow me to have the `import pkg.name.one.R; / import pkg.name.two.R;` replaced with a unified import statement?

I'm also open to other suggestions that would solve my syncing woes :)

Comment: its better to import `R in import statement` and remove unneccessary package using `CTRL+SHIFT+O`

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but did you put the duplicate code into a library project which you reference from each application or are the two apps completely separated and have 90% the same code? And you should keep the R file as it is, and not try to use the same for both projects

Comment: Move shared code to android library. Then include it in both applications.

Comment: Samir - I'm not sure what you mean here

Comment: banzai86 & dziobas - Most of my shared code has already been moved to an android library project, but I still insist on having my activities in the branches of the project itself. I have a lot of shared layouts and drawables but in some cases they are different

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you modify `RWrapper` to make `R` a static field instead of a class? Your code would then access `R` via `RWrapper.RClass...`

Example

```
public class RWrapper
{
  public static pkg.name.one.R R;
}
```

and

```
public class RWrapper
{
  public static pkg.name.two.R R;
}
```

You'd access the R fields with:

```
RWrapper.R.<blah>
```

Answer (score 0):

seggy had it almost right, but you need to expose each R.class individually. If the sub-module has it's own namespace then you can re-use the class name R and not need to modify anything in your sub-module.

```
package the.submodule.package;

public final class R {
public static the.app.package.R.string string;
public static the.app.package.R.drawable drawable;
public static the.app.package.R.id id;
//public static the.local.appPackage.R.anythingElse anythingElse;
}
```

Note: I'm not condoning sharing R across projects, but sometimes time constraints etc.